# Why do I get a FolderNotFoundException after successfully creating a folder?

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create a folder if it does not exist and then copy a message from another folder to the destination folder. I am finding some strange behaviour that I can not understand. Given the following excerpt:

```
// messages is an array of Message instances.
// Source is the source folder
// destination is a string of the destination folder.
Folder dest = null;
try {
    dest = store.getFolder(destination);
    if (!dest.exists()) {
        dest.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES | Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS);
        // Since folder's are not meant to cache I thought I'd get it again
        // though this does not work either.
        //dest.close(false);
        //dest = store.getFolder(destination);
    }
    dest.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    // Fails here
    source.copyMessages(messages, dest);
    source.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), true);
} catch (MessagingException ex) {
    throw new MailProcessorException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
} finally {
    if (dest != null) {
        try {
            dest.close(false);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't close destination folder.");
        }
    }
}
```

The following behaviour is examined:

- If the folder does not exist:

  1. The folder gets created
  2. An exception is thrown at `source.copyMessages`.
- If the folder does exist:

  1. The messages are copied as expected.
  2. Messages are marked for deletion.

I am using JavaMail 1.4.6, also tried with 1.6.5.

Comment: try change `if (!dest.exists())` to `while (!dest.exists())` and add `Thread.sleep(1000)` after creating the folder

Comment: No this does not work. I had previously put a debugging statement after the `create()` to output `dest.exists()` which would always print `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **really** strange. Looking at your code and reading the docs, there should be no way that this is happening...

Could it be some problem with the mail server? Some databases use consistency models (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency for example) that don't always act the way you'd naively expect. Is there a chance you can try your code on a different mail server? Or, try to put a really long (30 seconds?) `Thread.sleep(...)` before your `copyMessages(...)` call and see if that fixes it.

If it does, what is happening is that your server creates the folder in one request, but this creation takes a while to reach the part of the server code that is handling the message copying. Then, unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is much you can do other than a retry if the copying fails or the artificial delay (which sucks).

*Aside: The docs seem to say, that you can skip the `dest.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);` if you like*.

Comment: Markas that seems to be exactly what is occurring. I set a delay after folder creation to 10s, then; `copyMessages()` passes and behaves as expected. I am connecting to exchange 2007, I can try testing against something like GMail though I would need to investigate this when I have a little spare time. I think the solution would be to use a small delay combined with a retry limit to try again a few times if it fails. It's a pain in the butt that this needs to be done, but I guess it needs to be done :) Thanks so much for your help Markus.

Comment: :) Glad I could help! Exchange, ey? Go M$! Making our life easier one bug at a time...

Comment: lol, thanks :) I've raised [JavaMail bug 5822](http://kenai.com/bugzilla/post_bug.cgi) to see if this can be addressed in by Oracle, not sure on chances but it's worth a try, if only to help any other unsuspecting victims. There could be something that Oracle could check before returning a success/fail at a protocol level instead of hacky delays etc.

Comment: Please also note: A folder does not need to be opened to perform `copyMessages(Message[])` however, as I call `Folder.setFlags(...)` the folder must be opened.

Comment: @BrettRyan I think that should still be OK since you are calling the `Folder.setFlags(...)` on `source`, not `dest`. So, for this `dest` doesn't need to be opened either. ;) This might actually save you the entire try-finally block?

Comment: Well observed Markus. Unfortunately can't remove try/finally as almost all JavaMail calls seem to throw `MessagingException` or some form of it. I am surprised I don't get an exception on the source folder though :P Probably have something earlier in my call chain observing the folder already without me realising though. Wouldn't hurt for me to ad an `if (!source.isOpen())` check though.

Comment: What does the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when this happens?